# const correctness: how to get element from an iterator field while keeping the function const?

Tags: c++, const-correctness

I'm implementing a class `Foo` which has a `const_iterator` called `m_iter`. I want to implement

```
Bar* GetBar() const;
```

which simply

```
return &(*m_iter);
```

However, it triggers an error

```
cannot initialize return object of type 'Bar *' with an rvalue of type 'const Bar *'
```

My intention is to return a pointer to Bar without changing any internal state of the object (i.e. `m_iter`).

How can I do that?

Comment: If you make the function `const Bar* GetBar() const` you should be fine. Returning a pointer to a mutable object from the internals basically means you're no longer const. consider what happens if something does `GetBar()->SomeMutationOnBar();`

Comment: @Charlie What if I just want to ensure that the members of `Foo` (i.e. `m_iter`) are immutable and allow the users of `Bar` to mutate its contents?

Comment: I think you quickly get in to surprising behavior if you relax that. Especially if you get into multi-threaded code. If you want to return a non-const pointer, don't make the method `const`. Still a somewhat dangerous design from a long term maintainability perspective, and may point to a design deficiency, though it's hard to say with only the one line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `const_iterator` to an `iterator`. Even if your `Foo` class doesn't directly modify the `Bar` object pointed to by the iterator, it still needs to have the *right* to modify it if it wants to grant that right to someone else. Which is what it's trying to do by returning a non-const pointer.

Unless of course, it is not your intention to grant modify access to the `Bar` object. In that case, change the return type of the function to `const Bar*`.

Comment: I ended up changing const_iterator to iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest provide two functions, `const` version and a non-`const` version.

```
Bar* GetBar();
Bar const* GetBar() const;
```